# Circle CI saving result of expression to BASH_ENV

Tags: bash, grep, circleci, circleci-2.0

Having a lot of trouble grabbing the version from a package.json and saving it as an environment variable for another step in Circle CI.

Here's what I'm doing: `- run: "echo PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat TaiV_Web_App/package.json | grep version | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[\",]//g') >> $BASH_ENV" #Get package version`.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am doing a similar thing, but adapted it to fit your needs assuming you have `node` installed. This is a bit more of a fail proof way, so you do not need to rely of parsing the string yourself. Try doing it like this:

```
  - run:
      name: Determining package version
      command: |
          echo 'export PACKAGE_VERSION=$(node -pe "require(\"./package.json\").version")' >> $BASH_ENV

  - run:
      name: Echoing package version
      command: |
          echo ${PACKAGE_VERSION}
```

Hopefully this helps.